# How are the KL Divergence terms derived from the variational lower bound loss on diffusion models?

Tags: probability

In the last step of deriving the variational lower bound loss $L_{VLB}$ of a diffusion model (as copied from https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/):

$$
L_{VLB} = \mathbb{E}_{q}[\log \frac{q(x_{T}|x_{0})}{p_{\theta}(x_{T})}) 
+ \sum_{t=2}^T \log \frac{q(x_{t-1}|x_{t},x_{0})}{p_{\theta}(x_{t-1}|x_{t})})
- \log p_{\theta}(x_{0}|x_{1})]  \tag{1}
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}_{q}[D_{KL}(q(x_{T}|x_{0}) \lVert p_{\theta}(x_{T}))
+ \sum_{t=2}^T D_{KL}(q(x_{t-1}|x_{t},x_{0}) \lVert p_{\theta}(x_{t-1}|x_{t}))
- \log p_{\theta}(x_{0}|x_{1})] \tag{2}
$$

How are the first two terms in (1) equivalent to their respective KL Divergence terms in (2)?

Working backwards from the first KL term in (2):

$$
D_{KL}(q(x_{T}|x_{0}) \lVert p_{\theta}(x_{T}))
$$
$$
= \sum_{x_{T}}q(x_{T}|x_{0})\log \frac{q(x_T | x_0)}{p_{\theta}(x_{T})} \stackrel{?}{=} \log \frac{q(x_T | x_0)}{p_{\theta}(x_{T})} \tag{3}
$$

How does (3) hold?

Answer (score 0):

The following might answer the first question. For each term of (1),
\begin{align*}
    &\mathbb{E}_q\left[\log\left(\frac{q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)}{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}\right)\right]\\
    &\quad=\int dx_{0:T}q(x_{0:T})\log\left(\frac{q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)}{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}\right)\\
    &\quad=\int dx_{0:T}q(x_\ast|x_{t-1},x_t,x_0)q(x_{t-1},x_t,x_0)\log\left(\frac{q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)}{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}\right)\\
    &\quad=\underbrace{\int dx_\ast q(x_\ast|x_{t-1},x_t,x_0)}_{=1}\int dx_0dx_tdx_{t-1}\underbrace{q(x_{t-1},x_t,x_0)}_{=q(x_t,x_0)q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)}\log\left(\frac{q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)}{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}\right)\\
    &\quad=\int dx_0dx_tq(x_t,x_0)\int dx_{t-1}q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)\log\left(\frac{q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)}{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}\right)\\
    &\quad=\int dx_0dx_tq(x_t,x_0)D_{{\rm KL}}(q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)\Vert p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)),
\end{align*}
where $x_\ast$ indicates $x_{0:T}$ except $x_0$, $x_t$, and $x_{t-1}$. Please refer to Eq. (14) of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03585).